# postgres, django & general webserver auth security (pg_hba.conf etc)

Tags: django, postgresql, web-applications, webserver

I'm trying to set up my web server with best practices and general security in mind and have been reading up on as much as I can.

My server is running nginx & uwsgi which have both been set up to run to run as their respective users 'nginx' and 'uwsgi' - both users have been set up as no-login, no-password.

All my application/project folders are chown'ed under my own (non-root) user name and the group 'developers'. They are chmod'ed as read only to everyone.

**1st Question)**

My understanding is that this is good practice because the servers (uwsgi/nginx) have no write access to these files?

**2nd Question)**

My postgres **pg_hba.conf** is:

```
local    all    postgres    ident sameuser
local    appdb  appusername      password
```

where appdb & appusername have been setup through pgsql for a particular app

Does this mean that the (unix) user 'postgres' can only login locally when authorized by ident/unix?

Furthermore does it mean that the only access to the database 'dbname' is through the (psql) user 'dbuser' with the correct password

** Final Part **

If my server (uwsgi) technically has read access to my django settings file (which has my database details including password and psql username), is this not a security risk?

Any clarifications would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it is a good (although rare for web applications) practice for servers to not have write or read access to files it does not have to.
2. Yes it means that any process, which is run by postgres OS user, can access any database as postgres database user. And it is enforced by ident, but not insecure and unreliable network ident but local, secure and reliable SO_PEERCRED.

   I'd also recommend that services connect not by password but by local ident — if attacker gains somehow read privilege to settings file (for example from backups, insecure transfer etc.) with saved password then it can do anything to database. With ident it has to be able to run code as particular user, which is much harder.
3. Everything is a security risk. Security is an art of managing this risk — managing balance between secure and convenient. If you can configure your server that it does not need access to this files and it would not be overly impractical (for example needs manual intervention on reboot) then go for it. Maybe this "ident" authentication would be better.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's generally a good practice to be as paranoid about permissions as possible--so yes. :)
2. Yes, yes and yes.
3. Everything that's allowed is a "security risk" but sometimes it just doesn't work otherwise. uWSGI is your application server, how is he supposed to run your code, if it can't read it?